# MediaPlayer.Play() causes UI to freeze

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface, windows-phone-8, xna, freeze

Everytime `MediaPlayer.Play()` is executed from the UI thread the UI freezes for a significant amount of time. I don't think you can do anything about the time it takes to start playing the SongCollection but at least the UI should stay responsive.
Running `MediaPlayer.Play()` from another thread obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please.

Answer (score 1):

The MediaPlayer is a component from the Xna Namespace. If you are using this feature in a game, you are most certain running a GameLoop to prevent this freeze from happening:  [GameLoop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203873.aspx)

If you use this component in an App, you can simulate this behavior your own

```
public MainPage()
    {    InitializeComponent();
         // Timer to simulate the XNA Game Studio game loop (Microphone is from XNA Game Studio)
         DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
         dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
         dt.Tick += delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };
         dt.Start();
}
```

(see complete sample on how to run a microphone outside a gameloop: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442302%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))

Comment: So you mean I should put the rest of my project inside of a loop?

Comment: No. The loop would be a used in a game scenario. In your case, only add the dispatcherTimer in the page you are using the audio component

Comment: Ok, I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't fix the freezes.